# picking out data from 2 months ago only

Tags: sql

I'm currently using this which gives me all the data from the previous month.  So if i run it today in November, i get all of Octobers data.

Now i need to tweak this so it only shows data in September, and when we're in December will only show October etc

```
[DateTimeOfCall] between DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0)    and DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())+0, 0)
```

Thank you

Comment: what did you try? please add example data. please specify exacly what you want to get if you do the query on 1st nov and what you want to get if you query on nov 30th. additionally: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be

```
[DateTimeOfCall] between DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-2, 0)    
                     and DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE mydate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND now()